# Code by Zapier Get Unexpected Token When Inserting InputData variable into JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, zapier

Have been trying to insert inputdata.SKU into the payload below.  However, I get Unexpected Token error.

Complete Javascript code used in the Code by Zapier input box is below.  Note have replaced the token with XXXXXXX in endpoint variable for security reasons.

```
var endpoint = 'https://api.yotpo.com/apps/XXXXXX/purchases/';
var payload = {
  "validate_data": true,
  "platform": "general",
  "utoken": inputData.ACCESS_TOKEN,
  "email": inputData.EMAIL,
  "customer_name": inputData.CUST_NAME,
  "order_id": inputData.ORDER_ID,
  "order_date": inputData.ORDER_DATE,
  "currency_iso": "NZD",
  "products": { 
    inputData.SKU : {
      "url": inputData.URL, 
      "name": inputData.NAME, 
      "image": inputData.IMAGE_URL
    }
  }
};

fetch(endpoint, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify(payload)
  }).then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  }).then(function(responsebody) {
    var output = {response: responsebody};
    callback(null, output);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    callback(error);
  });
```

Comment: what is the value of your `inputData.SKU`? and where does the error point exactly?

Comment: Is a barcode/number like 9414123456789.

Comment: What do you mean by error point exactly?

Comment: Does the error message help with finding the error point?  SyntaxError: Unexpected token . Function (native) Domain.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:52:23) Domain.run (domain.js:228:14) module.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:51:5)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an expression, `inputData.SKU`, as a property name (key). Luckily, Zapier runs on node.js v4.3.2, so [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) are supported.

Try changing that line to this (wrap the expression in brackets):

`[inputData.SKU] : {`